# How to update duplicated values in an array with the latest added values in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am working with javascript and I have an array and I want to replace the duplicated values with the latest entered value by the user. The users enter DataName and the value for the data.
For example the user enters:

```
                             data.put value_a 50
                             data.put value_b 100
                             data.put value_a 200
                             data.put value_c 150
```

and thats what prints as the output:

```
                             value_a 200
                             value_b 100
                             value_c 150
```

As you can see value_a gets the value of the 200 which is the latest added value so 50 is replaced by 200.

Thats what I tried for creating the array and showing data but it does not remove the duplicates.

```
 var formatedData = [];
                    _.each(this.EnteredData, function(inputLine) {
                        if(inputLine.indexOf("data.set") !== -1){
                            var args = inputLine.split(" ");
                            if(args[0] === "data.set"){
                                if(!_.isUndefined(args[1]) && !_.isUndefined(args[2])){
                                        if(args[1].length !== 0 && args[2].length !== 0){
                                            var dataObj = {
                                            name : args[1],
                                            value : args[2]
                                            };
                                            formatedData.push(dataObj);
                                        }
                                }
```

//Displaying arrays

```
if(formatedData.length !== 0) {
                        $('#terminal').html(" Entered values are:\r\n");
                        _.each(formatedData, function(data) {
                            $('#terminal').append(data.name + " : " + data.value + "\r\n");
                        });
                        this.validatedData = formatedData.slice(0);
                        this.toggleSaveButton();
                    }
```

The above code shows all the entered value (including the duplicated ones) but I dont know how to update the duplicated values with the latest added element. Maybe I need associative or hash to replace them?

Any hint?

Thanks

Comment: what is going wrong in your code? ... do you see any errors? ... what is the desired result?

Comment: The code is right I dont know how to replace the duplicated ones with the latest added values.

Comment: So please try first ... just try ... if you fail somehow, them you ask for help.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `push` to add, and `print` to write values more simple :

if you need to replace old values with new values, you can use this functions which your keys is defined on `o` variable as a `property`, and when you get same key to adding value `o[key]` refer to existed property on `o`, and automatically, old value is changing to new value:

```
var o = {};
function push(key, value) {

    o[key] = value;
};

function print() {

    for (var i in o)
        console.log("key: " + i + ", value: " + o[i]);
};
```

and if you need old values too, you can use this functions which define `o` as an array, and keeps both old and new values:

```
var o = [];
function push(key, value) {

    o.push({ key: key, value: value });
};

function print() {

    for (var i = 0; i < o.length; i++) {

        console.log("key: " + o[i].key + ", value: " + o[i].value);
    }
};
```

also you can implement `print` by `forEach` which is soppurted by newer browsers (you can follow `LINQ to JavaScript` subjects to get more examples and explanations ...):

```
function print() {

    o.forEach(function (u) { console.log("key: " + u.key + ", value: " + u.value); });
};
```

Comment: Thanks, My code works correctly and shows all the entered value (including the duplicated ones) but I dont know how to update the duplicated values with the latest added element.

Comment: your code is so painful, you can acheive what you want very simple, like i said above

Comment: Thanks, but is your code updates the duplicated values with the new added one? How it look for duplicates?

Comment: yes, you said this, in your question `I want to replace the duplicated values with the latest entered value by the user`

Comment: i editted the post, to return old and new values for duplicated items

Comment: But your code prints all the values including duplicated ones. but I want to find the duplicated and replace them by the latest value that is added.

Comment: i wrote two functions before editting this post, which old values was replaced with new values automatically... and you commented this `but is your code updates the duplicated values with the new added one` i thought you need old values too, and replace that post with this post, i have to edit this post again, i think you had not tested my first functions, too their see results

Comment: post was completed, check it out, is it your answer ?

Comment: Your code does not work!! "key: " + i + ", value: " + o[i] in the for loop is going to replace old values with new ones? come on!

Comment: you are doing something wrong certainly, i posted TESTED functions, were you tested it ?, give me your values you want to add, to test, and write the results for you, if you can`t

Comment: yes, old values replaced by new values, i think you need to read some javascript documentations

Comment: i have to repeat what i said in the post again, have you read my post ?!!! `"your keys is defined on o variable as a property, and when you get same key to adding value o[key] refer to existed property on o, and automatically, old value is changing to new value"`

Comment: My values are :  data.put value_a 50 and data.put value_b 100 and when I tried  for (var i in o)
        console.log("key: " + i + ", value: " + o[i]); it shows all the values in the array. but in fact I just need to show value_b 100 which is the last one

Comment: you mean `"data.put value_a"` is `key` and `50` is `value` ? and you try my functions like this: `push("data.put value_a", 50)` ? but in output you want to show just `value_a` with latest value ?

Comment: Well, thats how I combined your code with mine. I get the name and value from what user enters var args = inputLine.split(" ");
       if(args[0] === "data.set"){
        if(!_.isUndefined(args[1]) && !_.isUndefined(args[2])){
          if(args[1].length !== 0 && args[2].length !== 0){
           var dataObj = {
           name : args[1],
           value : args[2]
           };
           // formatedParameters.push(paramObj);
           formatedParameters.push({name: dataObj.name, value:dataObj.value});
          }
        }

Comment: according to your comment, if user just enter all data in a string, you need to overwrite my `push` function to this: `function push(key){ var k = key.split(" "); if(k.length == 3 && k.every(function(u){ return u != null && u !="" && u !=" " })) o[k[1]] = k[2] }`

Answer (score 0):

according to all of our discussion, posts, and comments, 
if i was you, for input data, and validating if its in valid format or not,i was creating a proxy or manager, and i didnt mix validationg, pushing and getting data to other codes, 
you can even use this nub of code, as a library, and save all this, to a js, and use it in every page you want...
this kind of coding have so advantage
and finally, if i want to write this script, i was writing like this:

```
<script>

    +function () {

        //----------------------------------------------- linq extensions (these functions is added for older browsers)
        // if you need to learn what linq is, you can follow some documentations

        Array.prototype.forEach =
            Array.prototype.forEach ?
            Array.prototype.forEach :
            function (handler) {

                if (handler && typeof handler == "function") {
                    for (i = 0; i < this.length; i++)
                        handler(this[i]);
                }
        };

        Array.prototype.every =
            Array.prototype.every ?
            Array.prototype.every :
            function (handler) {

                var isValid = true;
                this.forEach(function (u) {

                    var result = handler(u);
                    isValid = isValid && result;
                });
                return isValid;
        };
        //----------------------------------------------- end linq extensions



        oProxy = new Proxy();                       // this is a manager that other has access only to this, and send request to this manager
        function Proxy() {                          // proxy class

            //------------ private members
            this.__o = {};                          // repository for data, as a dictionary
            //------------ end private members


            //------------ instance members
            this.Reset = function () {              // to reset proxy

                this.__o = {};
            };

            // your input is a string, that each part separate by a space
            // i called first part as type
            // second part as key
            // and third part as value
            this.Push = function (requestString) {  // add a value to dictionary, if it is valid

                var oProxyRequest = ProxyRequest.CreateRequest(requestString);
                if (oProxyRequest != null) {

                    var typeObject = this.__o[oProxyRequest.Type] || {};
                    typeObject[oProxyRequest.Key] = oProxyRequest.Value
                    this.__o[oProxyRequest.Type] = typeObject;

                    return oProxyRequest;
                }

                return null;
            };

            this.GetValues = function () {          // populate an array from dictionary, and return it, 
                                                    // every item on array has three property
                                                    // 1: Type
                                                    // 2: Key
                                                    // 3: Value

                var o = [];
                for (i in this.__o) {

                    var type = i;
                    var keyValuePairList = this.__o[i];
                    for (t in keyValuePairList) {

                        var key = t;
                        var value = keyValuePairList[key];

                        o.push(new ProxyRequest(key, value, type));
                    }
                }

                return o;
            };

            this.Print = function () {              // write items to console

                this.GetValues().forEach(function (u) {

                    console.log("Type: " + u.Type + ", Key: " + u.Key + ", Value: " + u.Value);
                });
            };
            //------------ instance members



            //----------------------------------------------- inner class
            function ProxyRequest(key, value, type) {

                this.Key = key;
                this.Value = value;
                this.Type = type;
            };                  // used to map string value to a type


            //------------ static members
            ProxyRequest.CreateRequest = function (requestString) {     // map input string to a ProxyRequest if input string was valid

                if (isValid(requestString)) {

                    var args = requestString.split(" ");
                    return new ProxyRequest(args[1], args[2], args[0]);
                }

                return null;
            };
            //------------ end static members


            //------------ private members
            function isValid(requestString) {                           // implementaion to validate input string

                if (requestString == null ||
                    requestString == undefined ||
                    requestString == "")
                    return false;


                if (requestString.indexOf("data.set") !== -1) {         // if you bypass this condition you can apply grouping
                                                                        // on keys, like this: every old key on its group replace by new key on that group
                                                                        // for example: 
                                                                        // you can add these two :
                                                                        // 1: "data.set value_a 100"
                                                                        // 2: "data.put value_a 200"
                                                                        // now you have two group and two key with values 100 and 200
                                                                        // but if you add this: "data.set value_a 500"
                                                                        // now you have "data.set value_a 500" and "data.put value_a 200"
                                                                        // but, by current implementation which you have
                                                                        // you can just add "data.set" as type
                                                                        // and all "keys" must be unique at this group
                                                                        // and by this explanation, if you add this twoL
                                                                        // 1: "data.set value_a 100"
                                                                        // 2: "data.set value_a 200"
                                                                        // you just have latest input "data.set value_a 200"


                    var args = requestString.split(" ");
                    if (args.every(function (u) { return u.length !== 0; }) &&
                        args[0] === "data.set") {

                        return true;
                    }
                }

                return false;
            };
            //------------ end private functions
            //----------------------------------------------- end inner class
        };

    }();

</script>
```

and you can use this encapsulated proxy with your other code, by this statement:

```
oProxy.Push("data.set value_a 100");
oProxy.Push("data.set value_b 200");
oProxy.Push("data.set value_a 300");

oProxy.Print();

oProxy.GetValues();

oProxy.Reset();
oProxy.Print();
```

you may think this proxy class has too lines of code, but it has very advantage

Comment: Wow! thanks, seems too complicated! I have no idea how to use it, is it in javascript? :D Is it possible to do it in jsfiddle?

Comment: its really hard for me to understand! mishe emaileto baram befresti? Merc

Comment: i wrote how to use this proxy, you just need to add my first script containing implementation inside of your js and simply use, as i said: to push, simply just call: `oProxy.Push("data.set value_a 100");`, to get, simply call: `oProxy.GetValues();`, to reset: `oProxy.Reset();`, and to write to console: `oProxy.Print();`, if my  posts were useful to you, get vote to them, and if they were your answer, check them as answer, for help to others, my email is, my display name in yahoo